# How to send an email once every 6 months using the Rules module?

Tags: 7, rules, emails

How to send an email once in every 6 months at `12:00 am` for a date field about user renewal which is there in user profile using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Its mail should send in cyclic form every once in 6 months to notify user, repeating the mail once in 6 months.

So far I followed the tutorial "[How to Send Follow-Up Emails Using Rules Scheduler in Drupal 7](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-send-follow-up-emails-using-rules-scheduler-in-drupal-7/)", and I have created a Rules Component, I then created a Rule like so:

- Rules Event: After saving a new user account
- Rules Conditions: None
- Rules Action: schedule the Rules component (which I created before), with Scheduled evaluation date:+6 month and User > Data Selector: account.

So this is what I have done so far and this email I want to send every 6 months once repeatedly same email

Comment: sorry, I don't have time for a full answer. I'll point you in the right direction. Google "rules scheduler"

Comment: @sssweat: i understand, well i have already installed the rules and created component and also set the rule but i dont know what exactly to do because by seeing many of the tutorial m getting confused and now finally m blank not getting what to do.:(:(:(:(:(:(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send user a reminder email after x-number of days if Profile2 field is empty and user has specific role](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117967/send-user-a-reminder-email-after-x-number-of-days-if-profile2-field-is-empty-and) - I know it's not exactly the same question but it seems answer there would fit here as well.

Comment: @molot: my requirement is to send every 6 month once and its just like cycle form it should notify user every 6 month once, am not able to find the solution for this, i am in hard time.

Comment: @kashish: It would be better, if you describe, what you have done so far and what doesn't work. You said, that you tried to learn from many tutorials - so do not ask for another one.

Comment: @MilošKroulík: so far i have  created a Rule COMPONENT

I then created a Rule...

Events: After saving a new user account

Conditions: None



Component: the component from step 1
Scheduled evaluation date:+6 month
User > Data Selector: account...........this is what i have done so far and this mail i want to send every 6 months once repeatedly same email

Comment: @kashish Plase move the steps you have taken to the question itself, so it's directly visible to all. Reagrding the question "will it trigger repeatedly each 6 months": did you try to temporarily set a short period, such as 1 minute and test if it's working?

Comment: @MilošKroulík:  i set the short period and result is whenever i run the cron the email is triggering and only one mail i got after running the cron.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84268/use-hook-cron-to-send-daily-mail-but-i-get-45-the-same-mail-every-day/275911#275911

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module together with `Rules Scheduler` (a sub-module of it), can be used for sending such eMails, as explained in the steps below.

#### Step 1: Create a field to store the "next renewal" date

Add a field to the "user" entity with machine name (say) `field_next_renewal`. Allow only 1 date (to store the "next" renewal date).

#### Step 2: Create a Rules "Component"

Here is the Rules **Component** to be created (in Rules export format, just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_send_email_notification" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send eMail notification",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user_to_notify" : { "label" : "User to be notified", "type" : "user" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "user-to-notify:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Reminder about your next renewal",
          "message" : "This is a reminder about your next renewal on [user-to-notify:field_next_renewal] ...",
          "from" : "[site:mail]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously, the ***Subject*** and ***Content*** of the eMail may need review / tuning, while you might also want to use some other ***From*** eMail ID.

#### Step 3: Create a "Rule" using the Rules Component

Here is the **Rule** to be created, in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format (just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_email_user_every_6_months" : {
    "LABEL" : "eMail user every 6 months",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "user_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "account" ], "field" : "field_next_renewal" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "account:field-next-renewal" ], "value" : "+6 month" } },
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_send_email_notification",
          "date" : {
            "select" : "account:field-next-renewal",
            "date_offset" : { "value" : 15552000 }
          },
          "identifier" : "[account:name]",
          "param_user_to_notify" : [ "account" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule refers to the *Rules Component* from the previous step.

Note that the `15552000` is the equivalent of 6 months in seconds. You may want to reduce that a bit, e.g. with a number of seconds equivalent to a few days (or a week or so). That way the eMail will be triggered a few days before the actual renewal.